# Try-Except Python Block stops Jenkins from showing any output

Tags: python, jenkins, printing, jenkins-groovy, try-except

I have a python script which is ran as part of a Jenkins job, the purpose of the script is to go through a for-loop and complete different tasks for each item, if one fails it should go to the next, hence why there is a Try-Except written as:

```
try:
    ~some code~
except Exception as e:
    print e
    continue
```

This try-except is added in the main function. The script has a bunch of print statements showing the status however whenever the try-except is added nothing is shown in Jenkins Blue Ocean as the pipeline runs. Is there anything I can do to force the print to show?

Answer (score 0):

From the lack of brackets I gather you're using python27? If not, python3 will throw an error as it enforces brackets. If this is then caught by another of these *bare* exception clauses (considered bad practice) you would simply miss the actual exception.

The `continue` is not necessary, this is not something I would expect in a `except` clause as it used to short-circuit a loop. There is actually no need to do anything after the print statement.

```py
try:
    # ~some code~
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

If this does not work you could consider switching to the logging library. This configures logging to output to STD OUT per default.

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    # ~some code~
except Exception as e:
    logger.warning(e)
```

If those suggestions do not work you can somewhat safely assume that Jenkins is somehow capturing output?

Answer (score 0):

The try except block should be in the for loop statement like.

```
            for i in range(x):
                try:
                   #your code
                except Exception as e:
                   print e
                   continue
```